# C file reader skips every other line

Tags: c, file, scanf

My goal is to load a .obj file in C, but my problem is that fscanf seems to skip every other line, instead of reading it smoothly. I haven't gotten any error messages.
I checked other questions, but I haven't called fscanf twice, or written anything not present in other file readers.

For example, 4 lines in the file look like:

```
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
```

But the output would be:

```
read from file: v, 1.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000
read from file: v, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000
```

Here is my code:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Primary vector function */
struct vec3d {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

/* Triangle structure of 3 vectors */
struct triangle {
  struct vec3d p1;
  struct vec3d p2;
  struct vec3d p3;
};

/* function to load an object file */
int main (){

    struct vec3d verts[256];
    struct triangle tris[256];
    int lastVertIndex = 0;
    int lastTriIndex = 0;

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("cube.obj", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char singleLine[128];

    while(!feof(fp)){
        fgets(singleLine, 128, fp);
        if(singleLine[0] == 'v' && singleLine[1] == ' '){
          struct vec3d v;
          char junk[2];
            
          fscanf(fp, "%s %f %f %f", &junk, &v.x, &v.y, &v.z);
          printf("read from file: %s, %f, %f, %f\n", junk, v.x, v.y, v.z);
          verts[lastVertIndex].x = v.x;
          verts[lastVertIndex].y = v.y;
          verts[lastVertIndex].z = v.z;
          lastVertIndex++;
        }

        if(singleLine[0] == 'f' && singleLine[1] == ' '){
          int f[3];
          char junk[2];
          fscanf(fp, "%s %f %f %f", &junk, &f[0], &f[1], &f[3]);
          tris[lastTriIndex].p1 = verts[f[0] - 1];
          tris[lastTriIndex].p2 = verts[f[1] - 1];
          tris[lastTriIndex].p3 = verts[f[2] - 1];
          lastTriIndex++;
        }
    };
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Just saying ".obj file" doesn't tell us what is in the file. In fact, obj files are commonly Windows binary files but you seem to be parsing it as a text file (so I assume it's not actually a binary obj file). So please clarify exactly what is in the file, what the expected output is and what the actual output is.

Comment: I assume your "obj" file is actually a file of coordinates of a 3D object, not a compiled file.  At any rate, I believe the reason you're processing every other line is that you read a line with `fgets` (the line goes into `singleLine`), but then you read _another_ line from the file with `fscanf`.  You probably want to do `sscanf( singleLine, ...)` instead of `fscanf( fp, ...)`.  (Otherwise, you need to provide an example of an OBJ file that you want to process.)

Comment: @DaveM. Your solution worked! Thank you very much. Regarding the formatting, I've updated the question to more accurately describe what I want to have happen, versus what the output was.